# Flutter await not waiting before continuing

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button in flutter where the onPressed function calls a future, as seen below.

```
await styling.dialog(
    context,
    "Update Username",
    "Update",
        () async { // This is the passed onPress method.
      if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        final FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData = new FirebaseUserData();
        await firebaseUserData.updateUsername(textController.text); // This is the future<void>
        displayName = textController.text; // This code runs before the above await has finished.
        Navigator.pop(context);
        setState(() {});
      }
    },
);
```

I cannot figure out why this happens. Please note that the onPressed function above gets passed to a dialog in another class (my own custom dialog), but the setState works so I guess there is nothing wrong here.

The `updateUsername` method can be seen below.

```
Future<void> updateUsername(String username) async {
    return await firestoreUsersCollectionReference
        .getDocuments().then((allUsersDocuments) {
      allUsersDocuments.documents.forEach((userDocument) async {
        if(userDocument.documentID == currentFirebaseUser.displayName) {

          final UserUpdateInfo updateUser = UserUpdateInfo();
          updateUser.displayName = username;
          await currentFirebaseUser.updateProfile(updateUser);
          currentFirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();


          Map<String, dynamic> newUserData() =>
          {
            describeEnum(fieldNames.itemsCollected): [],
            describeEnum(fieldNames.monstersCollected): [],
            describeEnum(fieldNames.profile): [],
            describeEnum(fieldNames.scannedBarcodes): [],
            describeEnum(fieldNames.settings): [],
            describeEnum(fieldNames.team): [],
          };

          await firestoreUsersCollectionReference.document(username).setData(newUserData());
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

The `updateUsername` methods runs to the end and it succeeds without problem.

Comment: This usually happens when you call a function instead of passing a reference. i.e. you use `onPressed: doSomething()` instead of `onPressed: doSomething` or `onPressed: () => doSomething()`. In that case `doSomething()` is executed and the result is passed to `onPressed`, this is not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your methods, but I suspect the issue is this:

```dart
allUsersDocuments.documents.forEach((userDocument) async {
  ...
});
```

You are using an `async` anonymous method in a `forEach`, which doesn't respect the returned futures and wait for them to complete. This is basically going to just fire off a bunch of futures (one for each element in `documents`) and then return without seeing what they do.

I would suggest either using a normal `for` loop:

```dart
for (var userDocument in allUserDocuments.documents) {
  ...
}
```

Or use `Future.forEach`:

```dart
await Future.forEach(allUserDocuments.documents, (userDocument) async {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Note that `Future.forEach` will wait for each operation *in sequence*.  If each operation is independent of the others, using `Future.wait()` would be better; that would wait for all operations to complete without any enforced order.

Answer (score 2):

```
return await firestoreUsersCollectionReference
    .getDocuments().then((allUsersDocuments)
```

the `then` method should not be used.

you need to do something like

```
final allUserDocuments = await firestoreUsersCollectionReference.getDocuments();
 allUsersDocuments.documents.forEach((userDocument {
        if(userDocument.documentID == currentFirebaseUser.displayName)

  }
```

after for each, there is no async keyword also because you might want to run it serially.

At the end return from the method, not at the beginning (it is required for breaking statements into multiple lines).

Comment: The `await future.then(...)` pattern is awkward (and I discourage its use whenever possible) but it isn't strictly wrong. The call to `then` returns its own future when its inner code finishes executing, so awaiting the `then` rather than the future it's called on would still cause the `async` method to wait properly.